# Magento Multi Stores & Websites

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I want  to  step up  the  multistore in magento.In our approach different product prices ,different sku , different shipping & different prices.

Three stores such as  Canada,Us & International.

Could somebody please advice in what to do and what is best approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials on the web:

Some of great are below:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup

If you don't want to do it by .htaccess file, then below link provides way to create multi store by copying and modifying index.php:

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-up-and-manage-multiple-stores.html

I hope I could help you.